# Calling controller method from view -Page not found

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, url-routing

I am trying to call a controller method from View. I tried to call it from Action link.

ActionLink is in Accounts View:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(item.ClientName,"GetDetails","DetailsController", new { id = item.Id 
  }, null)
```

DetailsController method:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id)
    {
      return View("ClientDetails", clientAccount);
    }
```

Url generated: https://localhost:44355/DetailsController/GetDetails/1

I am getting an error

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44388/DetailsController/GetDetails/1
HTTP ERROR 404

I need to redirect to clientDetails view and show data
Can I call like this? Is there any better method?

Folder structure
[image]

Comment: is Accounts view in a different area ? please share folder structure for your solution

Comment: Attatched. Shoud i add any routing in clientDetails controller?

Comment: you should add folder with same name of controller in views folder for each controller for example for AccountController you should have folder inside Views folder Called "Account" that will contains all views for Account Controller Action Methods

Comment: I have created a separate folder for the View. Now the page is loading. But the files such as css,bootstrap etc are not loading(404 error) .It is trying to load from https://localhost:44388/ClientDetails/GetClientDetails/css/bootstrap-reboot.css. If am directly loading the page(https://localhost:44355/clientdetails) styles are not breaking

Comment: @Reshma, For the static file 404 error, by default, in asp.net core application, the static files are stored in the project's `wwwroot` directory. From the screenshot, it seems that you are create a Style folder. So I assume perhaps these files are stored outside of web root, and you have changed the default static file directory, right? If you change it, you have to change these file paths (in your view page and the layout page). More detail information, check [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: I am using the root folder only. I add the style <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
 and now its not breaking .
 but When I am using ActiveLink the url is https://localhost:44388/DetailsController/GetDetails/1 , so the 'id' i am passing is exposed. also, I need to refer the common stylesheets again. Is there any other way to achieve this so that my url will not be having id in that.

Comment: Hi @Reshma, As we discussed in previous reply, even though the file name contains the `Controller`, such as: "DetailsController.cs", when using ActiveLink to create hyperlink, the controller name should be "Details", instead of "DetailsController". Then, the id parameter "1" is transferred via route, so it will be added at the end of the URL, if you don't want to expose it, you could consider submitting the form to the controller action and use a hidden field to store the id parameters. For using the common CSS style, please check the view page, make sure they are using the same layout page.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ryan noticed there is a typo in a ActionLink definintion. Change controller name from "DetailsController" to "Details"

The application looking for a view in a folder with a controller name in views folder. After this looking in Shared folder. It is a better way to put a view in Views folder with controller name. But if you need to make some exeptions, you  can specify the whole path to the view:

```
return View("~/Views/ClientAccount/ClientDetails.cshtml", clientAccount);
```

or put the view in  Shared folder.

Comment: it'll work but I don't recommend this as this not a good convention, better to move ClientDetails view to folder with the same name of controller ClientDetails

Comment: But problem is actually with routing (HTTP 404), not with .cshtml file location, is not it? It is required to change controller name in anchor link to this: `Details`, not the `DetailsController`. This naming convention is old as MVC itself. It is weird nobody noticed that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn' t notice  this, but after this it will give a page exeption.

Answer (score 0):

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
> address: https://localhost:44388/DetailsController/GetDetails/

For this issue, from the folder structure, it seems that in your application there have a ClientDetails controller, instead of the "Detail" controller.

So, when you create hyperlink, the controller name should be "ClientDetails", instead of "ClientDetailsController", code as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ClientName,"GetDetails","ClientDetails", new { id = item.Id}, null)
```

Then, I suppose the GetDetails method is in the ClientDetails controller, and the ClientDetails.cshtml page is in the Views/ClientAccount folder, if that is the case, we should use the following code to assign the view page.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id)
    { 
        var clientAccount = items.Where(c=>c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View("~/Views/ClientAccount/ClientDetails.cshtml", clientAccount);
    }
```

Because, if using `return View("ClientDetails", clientAccount);`, it will find the ClientDetails view page from the folder (which name is same with the controller name) in the Views folder.